# QGIS how can I open my own map into QGIS (not an Open Street Map)?

Tags: qgis, historical-maps

I am working on a project, that shows a list of German institutes financed by a treaty in the year 1949. Therefore I need to work with an historical map of this year, which I have.
How can I upload this map into QGIS?

Comment: Which data type does your map have? What happens when you drag&drop it into QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Can you post a image of (a section) of the map? It will be important to try to figure out the map projection (which may or may not be explicitly listed on the map in enough detail), and also decide whether you georeference specific points on the map, or have a grid you use instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing a map from 1949 is paper. Scan it and use Raster > Georeferncer to import it and align it to the other data you are using. (Load Open Street Map into QGIS and use it as a base to align the 1949 map)

Comment: For georeferencing, see the official documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html?highlight=georeference

Comment: or consult a tutorial, e.g. this one by Klas Karlsson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1X1U8255Q0